# Android: Reference R.string.blah based on a method input

Tags: android, string, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

I have 3 strings in my **strings.xml**.

```
<string name="string1">Hello from string1</string>
<string name="string2">Hello from string2</string>
<string name="string3">Hello from string3</string>
```

Now, I have a method that I pass a string like "**string1**" or "**string2**":

```
void showStringToast(String sName) {
    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.[sName]), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**How do I properly reference R.string.sName when sName is being passed as a parameter?**

Answer (score 2):

you can pass parameter to your string using like:

```
<string name="string1">Hello from %1$s (or $d if you want to pass integer) %2$d (second parameter)</string>
```

Now pass parameter from getstring method:

`getString(R.string.string1,first parameter ,second parameter ...);`[image]

see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

```
// try this
void showStringToast(String sName) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(getResources().getIdentifier(sName, "string", getPackageName())), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this code but I believe you could make use of HashMaps instead.

Declare a static HashMap somewhere, let's say in Constants.java

```
public static HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

then initialize your map. This must be inside a method or constructor

```
map.put("string1", "Hello from string1");
map.put("string2", "Hello from string2");
map.put("string3", "Hello from string3");
```

Now you can find your String with something like:

```
Toast.makeText(this, Constants.map.get(sName).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Don't forget to import Constants.java

Answer (score 0):

R.string.something is an integer value that contains a reference to your string. So , R.string.something is like a variable here. Have you ever done such thing that you have generated a variable by appending some string to make it like a variable name and your generated variable name working like a variable ? :)

Instead you can do like this. In your java source file , take your required string values to a String array from your resources. Then use them when necessary. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This way:

```
  void showStringToast(int sName) {
Toast.makeText(this, getString(sName), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```